# Realm .Net decryption is failing unexpected. [Xamarin Forms Project] [IOS + Android]

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

Getting below runtime crash log :

[libc++abi] terminating with uncaught exception of type realm::util::DecryptionFailed: Decryption failed
[libc++abi] Exception backtrace:
[libc++abi] 
[libc] Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 18743 (edisize.ida0120), pid 18743 (edisize.ida0120)

Comment: Realm V10.9.1
Xamarin Forms V5.x

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, there are known issues around encryption with older versions of Realm. The file is likely unrecoverable as it's now corrupted. We recommend you to update to the latest version of our SDK since we've addressed these known issues, Then try again with another file and if the problem persists, please open a github issue.